# tidy evaluation in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, tidyeval

This is a question about the codes in `vignette("in-packages")`

The dataset is below.

```
(mini_iris <- iris %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    .[c(1, 2, 51, 52, 101, 102), ])
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#> 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    
#> 3          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 4          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 5          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
#> 6          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
```

If the column names are in a character vector (possibly from a function call), you can provide that to one_of()

```
nest_egg <- function(data, cols) {
  nest(data, egg = one_of(cols))
}

nest_egg(mini_iris, c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species               egg
#>   <fct>      <list<df[,4]>>
#> 1 setosa            [2 × 4]
#> 2 versicolor        [2 × 4]
#> 3 virginica         [2 × 4]
```

And then, vignette describes that

> The use of `one_of()` here is important; if you don’t use it, and data contains a column named cols, `nest()` will nest it instead of the columns named in cols.

I think it can be solved in using **tidy evaluation**.

```
library(rlang)
nest_egg2 <- function(data, cols) {
  cols <- enexprs(cols)
  nest(data, egg = !!!cols)
}
nest_egg2(mini_iris, c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))
```

but it shows error

```
Error: `!!!` can't be supplied with a name. Only the operand's names are retained.
```

In next section, Vignette describes that

> To provide an interface that works like the tidyr function that you’re wrapping, you should pass the argument along using {{ arg }}. {{ }} is a special tidy eval operator that captures the expression supplied by the user and forwards it to another tidy eval-enabled function.

```
nest_egg <- function(df, cols) {
  nest(df, egg = {{ cols }})
}

nest_egg(mini_iris, -Species)
```

But I wonder what my `nest_egg2` has problem in

Comment: Yeah, I trying to solve `nest_egg2`

Comment: It works if you do `nest_egg2 <- function(data, cols) {
  cols <- enquo(cols); nest(data, egg = !! cols)
}`

Comment: To be clear, your goal is to have a function where you can supply bare column names like you would do with `dplyr`, etc functions? Or do you want to give column names as a character vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In selection contexts (not in action contexts like in `mutate()`), you can use `!!!` inside `c()` if you need to give a name:

```r
nest_egg <- function(df, cols) {
  nest(df, egg = c(!!!cols))
}
```

Since tidyselect also supports vectors of names, you can also simply unquote it, both approaches are valid:

```r
nest_egg <- function(df, cols) {
  nest(df, egg = !!cols)
}
```

The unquoting makes sure the env-variable `cols` is chosen over the data-variable `cols`, for the case that `df` has a column named `cols.

But really the proper way in selection contexts is to simply use `one_of()` (or `all_of()` in the next version).

Answer (score 0):

So there are two things here;

1. nest function takes a vector however enexprs returns a list
2. You do not need (bang bang/eval) for nest. Mostly evaluation is needed is the function calls the name of a column without quotations "", however in your case because cols is already a vector of a string it will work fine without evaluation.

So this should work;

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mini_iris <- 
  iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  .[c(1, 2, 51, 52, 101, 102), ]

nest_egg2 <- function(data, cols) {
  nest(data, egg = cols)
}

nest_egg2(mini_iris, c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# Species               egg
# <fct>      <list<df[,4]>>
# setosa            [2 x 4]
# versicolor        [2 x 4]
# virginica         [2 x 4]
```

Comment: Starting with the next version, supplying env-variables like that will trigger a message. In the future this will be deprecated. The proper way to do it is to use `one_of()` (current version) or `all_of()` (next version). See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/news/index.html#tidyselect-1-0-0-development.